# Python- is there a module that will automatically scrape the content of an article off a webpage?

Tags: python, algorithm, screen-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

I know there is lxml and BeautifulSoup, but that won't work for my project, because I don't know in advance what the HTML format of the site I am trying to scrape an article off of will be. Is there a python-type module similar to Readability that does a pretty good job at finding the content of an article and returning it?

Comment: this was asked earlier today, was it you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Instapaper-like algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283418/instapaper-like-algorithm)

Comment: Not really a duplicate. I think OP wants a readability.js like module in python, which is fair to ask. It's just not worded clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to do using [PhantomJS](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/) (C++) or [PyPhantomJS](http://dev.umaclan.com/projects/pyphantomjs) (Python).

They're both headless WebKit based browsers, which you can fully control from JavaScript. Because you can control it from JavaScript, I find it is really easy to do stuff such as scrape the content of an article.

[PyPhantomJS](http://dev.umaclan.com/projects/pyphantomjs) also has a plugin system, so that's definitely a plus. :)

Comment: You might also be interested in knowing about a JavaScript page scraping library that uses the above programs. :) [GitHub](https://github.com/nrabinowitz/pjscrape) | [Post on Google Groups](http://groups.google.com/group/phantomjs/browse_thread/thread/8b4cf134b51ad283)

Answer (score 0):

Extracting the *real* content from a content-page can not be done automatically - at least not with the standard tools. You have to define/identify where the real content is stored (by specifying the related CSS ID or class in your own HTML extraction code).

Comment: Of course it can be done automatically. It might be harder and require a fair bit of machine learning or other fancy algorithms, and it will probably not be 100% effective, but I bet you that it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Using HTQL, the query is: 
&html_main_text